# FTC Double Derivative of Two Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I need help working through this FTC problem I've encountered. It looks like such:

$$\frac{d^{2}}{d x^{2}}\left(\int_1^{\sin (x)}\left(\int_1^t\sqrt{1+u^2} d u\right)dt\right)$$

I know that in such cases, you can just substitute the bounds of the leftmost integral for the bounds of the right integral, then just multiply the derivative of the upper bound times $f(\text{upper bound})$. This can be seen [here](https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781285741550-stewart-calculus-early-transcendentals-8th-edition/426/problems-plus/12/).

$$\frac{d^{2}}{d x^{2}}\left(\int_1^{x}\left(\int_1^{sin(t)}\sqrt{1+u^4} d u\right)dt\right)$$

However, I'm not sure how to handle it when the $\sin(x)$ is in the outer integral. My first thought is to do $\arctan()$ of something to get it in the form of $x$ for substitution, but I really don't know. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain more in detail what is your problem? What do you mean with $\sin x$ is in the outer integral ?

Comment: I've edited the question to better show the example I'm referencing. From the link in my comment, you can see how the question solver goes about removing the two integrals, substituting the x where the t was in sin(t) bound. I'm wondering if this same technique can be used in reverse with the problem question so that the inner integrals' bounds become just sin(x) instead of t.

Answer (score 2):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, if $g(u)$ is a "nice" function and you define the function $F(x)$ by
$$
F(x) = \int_0^x g(u) du,
$$
then
$$
\frac{d}{dx} F(x) = g(x).
$$
In your problem, you are differentiating a function that looks like
$$
(F \circ \sin)(x) = F(\sin x) = \int_0^{\sin x} g(u) du.
$$
To differentiate functions like this, you would use the chain rule. And in particular,
$$
\frac{d}{dx} F(\sin x) = F'(\sin x) \cos x.
$$

Fortunately, as we noted above, you know the derivative of $F$. In your case, you happen to have an annoying function $g(u)$ and you will be wanting to compute a second derivative --- you'll need to use the fundamental theorem of calculus (twice total), the chain rule (twice total), and the product rule in the second derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the functions $F(x) = \int_1^{\sin x} t \, dt$ and $G(x) = \int_1^x \sqrt{1 + u^2} \, du.$ Observe that we have $$F(G(x)) = \int_1^{\sin x} \int_1^t \sqrt{1 + u^2} \, du \, dt,$$ hence by the Chain Rule, it follows that $$\frac{d^2}{d^2 x} \int_1^{\sin x} \int_1^t \sqrt{1 + u^2} \, du \, dt = \frac{d^2}{d^2 x} F(G(x)) = \frac d {dx} \biggr[ F'(G(x)) G'(x) \biggl] \phantom{blah blah blah bl}$$ $$\phantom{\frac{d^2}{d^2 x} \int_1^{\sin x} \int_1^t \sqrt{1 + u^2} \, du \, dt = \frac{d^2}{d^2 x} F(G(x))}= F'(G(x)) G''(x) + F''(G(x)) [G'(x)]^2.$$ Further, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we have that $F'(x) = \sin x \cos x$ and $G'(x) = \sqrt{1 + x^2}.$ Can you finish the solution from here? (Hint: you will need to implement the Product Rule to compute $F''(x)$ and the Chain Rule to compute $G''(x).$)

Comment: I'm trying to visualize what the F'(G(x) would look. Wouldn't it just be the sin(x)cos(x) with the entire G(x) function where the x's are?

Comment: Exactly. We have that $F'(G(x)) = \sin(G(x)) \cos (G(x)).$ Observe that $f(x) = \sqrt{1 + x^2}$ is differentiable for all $x \geq 1,$ hence $f(u) = \sqrt{1 + u^2}$ is integrable on the closed interval $[1, x]$ for all $x \geq 1.$ One could therefore find a closed form for $G(x),$ but I don't see why it is necessary for this problem.

Comment: the G(x)'s in sin(G(x)) and cos(G(x)) don't have any derivatives on them, so won't I be forced to evaluate G(x) definite integral to be able to do something with them inside the sin(x) and cos(x)? Also, does the second G'(x) in G(x)^2 come from the fact that taking the second derivative of F(x) forces a chain rule of G(x)?

Comment: No. Using the definition $G(x) = \int_1^x \sqrt{1 + u^2} \, du$ is fine. For your second question, yes. By the Chain Rule applied to $F'(G(x)),$ we obtain $F''(G(x)) G'(x).$ But there was already a factor of $G'(x)$ on this term by the Product Rule, so we have $F''(G(x)) [G'(x)]^2.$

Comment: In fact, no matter how you choose to solve this problem, you cannot rid yourself of $G(x)$ in some form. For instance, if you solve the problem as davidlowryduda has, you still wind up with $\int_1^{\sin x} \sqrt{1 + u^2} \, du.$